# Does async.series/async.waterfall work inside post method?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, post, async.js

I have used async.series inside my post method, but it does not seem to work, when call the post request the page says 404 not found.

```
router.route('/brandinsert')
.post((req, res, next) => {
    console.log("inside post"); //terminates here
    async.series({
        one: (callback) => {
            uploadImageOne(req, res, (err) => {
                console.log('Inside uploadImageOne');
                callback(req, res, err);
            });
        },

        two: (callback) => {
            uploadImageTwo(req, res, (err) => {
                console.log('Inside uploadImageTwo');
                callback(req, res, err);
            });
        },
    }, (req, res, err) => {
         console.log('Inside req,res,err'); //does not reach here
        if(err){
            console.log('error :' + err); //does not reach here
            if (err == 'Error: imageExtensionError') {
                res.json({
                    status: false,
                    msg: "File has invalid extension"
                });
            } else if (err == "Error: File too large") {
                res.json({
                    status: false,
                    msg: "File size exceed the limit,Allowed limit is 3 MB"
                })
            } else {
                console.log("err else section:" + err);
                res.json({
                    status: false,
                    msg: genericErrorMessage
                })
            }
        }else{
            console.log("Inside else of insert");
            let brandHeaderImg = req.body.brandHeaderImg;
            let brandLogoImg = req.body.brandLogoImg;
            let errorArray = [];
            let msg = null;
            //insert images into db
        }
    });
})
```

I am not getting what I am doing wrong, can anyone help? I am fairly new to node.js, pardon me if the questions seems silly.

Comment: Does any of your code in the bottom callback ever create a response using `res`?

Comment: Yes, `async.series()` and `async.waterfall()` work just fine in a route handler (If you use them properly).  We could help better if we could see all  your real code for this router handler. 
 With very little real code, all we can do is make guesses.  Here's my first guess.  Are you calling `next()` in your `.post()` handler?  If so, that will get to your default 404 handler before your async code completes.  If you are sending a response yourself and do not want further routing to occur, then do not call `next()`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts please check the edits I just made

Comment: That doesn't help at all.  It's still just pseudo-code.  You can put a `console.log()` in the completion callback of your  `async.series()` call to see if it gets there.  Nothing we can do to test that.

Comment: @jfriend00 no I am not calling next inside `.post()`

Comment: When you call the callback in `async`, the error value is the FIRST argument, not the last one.  Also, `if(err) throw err` should NEVER be used in asynchronous code.  It does nothing useful.  You should send an error response.

Comment: Also, it is a common convention with Express that if you're not going to call `next()`, then don't declare the argument at all.  That makes your code a bit clearer on its intent.

Comment: @jfriend00 I will remove the next, I just added `if(err) throw err` as pseudo code, please check the edits I just made

Comment: Did you see my previous comment about where the `err` argument goes in the async callback?  Your code appears to be wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00 I need the err arg to check for image related errors, and I have used it before and it has worked. my problem is the post method async.series itself is not being invoked.

Comment: If you put a `console.log()` in your `one` and `two` functions, does it get there?

Comment: No it doesn't, it just terminates right before the `async.series`

Comment: Well, step into it in the debugger and see what's going on inside the async library then.  You are apparently using it wrongly or it would at least call one of your functions.  You may also want to put a `try/catch` around the innards of your request handler so you can log if anything is throwing.

Comment: are you sure that you are hitting the right API because 404 means resource not found, also does any of above console gets printed?

Comment: @SAGARRAVAL yes its hitting the right api, no. only the first `console.log('inside post')` gets printed

Answer (score 0):

The callbacks in the async library need to be invoked as:

```
callback(err, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

with the `err` argument first and other optional arguments after it.  If there is no error and you wish processing to continue, then you pass `null` for the error:

```
callback(null, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

---

FYI, the trend in Javascript development is to "promisify" any async operations you have (create a wrapper that returns a promise instead of using a plain callback) and then use promise and `async/await` functionality for asynchronous control flow and error handling.  I would strongly recommend writing new code that way rather than using the async library with traditional callbacks.

node v10 even includes a promisified version of the `fs` library and more and more of the node internals are using promises and `async/await` now.

Comment: I change the way I was invoking the async lib, but the problem still persists. I agree with you about the trend to promisify. But I wanted to achieve it using async.series or async.waterfall